# Convergence of $\sum x^n$ in $C([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Consider the space of continuous functions $C([0,1])$. Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ converge in this space?

The series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n$ converges if the sequence $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of partial sums converges to some $g \in C([0,1])$.

So I need to find out if $\|s_n-g\|_\infty \to 0$, when $n \to \infty$. I know that $f_n(x)=x^n$ converges to $$f(x) =\begin{cases} 0, \ 0 \le x <1 \\ 1, \ x = 1 \end{cases}$$
but I don't think this limiting function will be very useful here?

Comment: (1) If $s_N(x)$ denotes the partials sums of your series, consider $s_N(1)$. What do you think happens for large values of $N$? (2) I think your pointwise limit is incorrectly written. Did you mean $f(x)$ is $0$ for $0 \leq x < 1$ and $1$ for $x = 1$?

Comment: Notice that the partial sums $s_n(x)=\sum^n_{k=1}$ have $|s_n(1)-s_m(1)|=|m-n|\leq\|s_n-s_m\|_u$. There is not change of $s_n$ being a Cacuhy sequence in $C(0,1]$ with the uniform norm.